# Keyboard is not displayed in iOS5 when the view is called in a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios5, keyboard

I have a UITextField in a view, however, when I call this view via "pushViewController" into a control or UIViewController UITabBarController in IOS5, the keyboard is not displayed.

There is only one element in any application window.

Could anyone tell me what the solution to this problem, since the iOS 4.3 works perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

Just try 
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
in the case of keyboard not displaying